# jquery colpick color plugin, programmatically set color

Tags: jquery, color-picker

How to set color to elements that is initialized with [jQuery's **colpick** plugin.](http://colpick.com/plugin)
like

```
$('#bg-color').colpick();
```

Is there any method to set colour so that the element's color is changed with value of the hidden color input field.
I am expecting a function may be like

```
$('#bg-color').setColor('#fff');
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using the plugin  event callbacks documented in API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, It is pretty simple

```
$('#bg-color').colpickSetColor('ffffff');
```

however it wont work properly if written as

```
$('#bg-color').colpickSetColor('fff');
```

or

```
$('#bg-color').colpickSetColor('#fff');
```